# Android Studio: Buttons not showing up during editing mode in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have tried looking up many solutions for this issue, but none have worked for me. Here is my .xml code for my main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:text="9" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my Java code:

```
package com.example.jacob.calculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I don't know if something is missing in my code, or if something is wrong with android studio. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Remove `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`

Comment: I just applied the changes. Nothing happened.

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with your IDE.....Did you try restarting the Android Studio

Comment: Yeah, still nothing.

Answer (score 2):

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

these attribute is used in ConstraintLayout not RelativeLayout, while in relativelayout if you want to determine the relative position between widget, you should use

> android:layout_below="@id/rl_all_day"

if you want to determine the relative position between child and parent, you should use

> android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

it's unnecessary to use both alignPargentStart and alignParentLeft

Comment: When I deleted alignParentLeft, it warned me against that and told me to add it back in order to support older versions of Android. Also, I removed the ConstraintLayout codes, but nothing worked.

Comment: Well elaborate .

Comment: When I said ConstraingLayout codes, I meant like app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent", and the other three.

Comment: When you remove the ConstraintLayout codes, do you add some other attribute to the textview? such as android:layout_alignParentEnd="true", maybe your button is coverd by textview. By the way, you can try File->invalidate Caches / Restart... to reboot your Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

Try using `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` because `LinearLayout` gives you more exposure to the coding and helps in creating more dynamic content.

Here's the code for `LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:text="9" />

</LinearLayout>
```

To make spaces in between either use **View** tag in XML or add **Padding** to the respective element.

To add padding:

```
android:padding="25dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

If Preview not work in your IDE, change gradle dependencies like below

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleDependency
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**solution is downgrade support libraries version to `alpha1`**

Comment: at build.gradle(Project) file